# Creating a periodical service in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm trying to create a periodical service where I can validate certain values stored on my mobile with the data I have on my API Server. If a user's password gets changed or if the user gets deleted the API Server should send a response back so the mobile app knows the user should be signed out. The request/response is not the problem. Just having issues getting the service periodically.

MyService.class:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";


    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
        // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Log.d(TAG,"loop service");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Restore interrupt status.
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Inside the onCreate of another random class:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Intent i= new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);
i.putExtra("KEY1", "Value to be used by the service");
mContext.startService(i);
```

The service does start (it shows me the Log.d), how do I continue from here to get it restarted or to make it start after certain time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: IntentService is designed only to execute a queue of tasks off the main thread. So you must create a new one every time you want to check for updates: for that see [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

But this is not necessarily the best way to do it. Instead of you polling the server for changes, try the [push notifications](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) approach.